# Using dask with cythonized classes. Error with pickling of object method

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, dask, cythonize

I'd like to cythonize a python module with the following class:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @staticmethod
    def f(k):
        return k

    def g(self, k):
        return self.x, k
```

After installation of cythonized module I'm trying to execute the code:

```
from dask import delayed, multiprocessing
c = C(3)
l = []
for i in range(10):
    l.append(delayed(c.f)(i))

results = delayed(l).compute(num_workers=2, get=multiprocessing.get)
```

I've got the pickling error (the same for static and non-static method):

```
~/anaconda/envs/cython_env/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py in save_global(self, obj, name, 
pack)
    621             self.save_dynamic_class(obj)
    622         else:
--> 623             raise pickle.PicklingError("Can't pickle %r" % obj)
    624 
    625     dispatch[type] = save_global

PicklingError: Can't pickle <cyfunction C.f at 0x113582b10>
```

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

my guess is u shouldn't use shared object or variables if u r going to use multiprocessing . u can use it with multithreading though . In your case, class C is the problem . u r passing the same object of c to delayed